# How to install Ubuntu on another partition? from image, w/o CD, w/o flash-stick

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iso-image

I have one installation of Linux that I want to abandon, and I would like to install Ubuntu on another partition. The problem is that this miniPC does not have a CD-drive and I don't have flash-stick here. (I'm on a vacation in kinda "detached" location. :)

Is it possible to prepare partition using ISO-image so that one could boot right into installation process? As if the image was on a bootable CD-ROM. I have this image-file ready on the "old" Linux user home.
|I would like to avoid netboot this time: i386 does freeze right after hitting Install in the boot menu; and my attempt to install amd64 ended up with Ubuntu that I'm not able to start in graphical mode.)

So I would like to install Ubuntu from ISO w/o CD or flash-stick, just to be sure I did not mess up the installation due the netboot.

P.S.: If it is not obviousy enough, I'm Linux noob. :)

Comment: You should be able to ask Grub to boot from the iso or the the kernel and ramdisk extracted from the iso. I have never tried this though.

Comment: It should be possible to run the installation from the other linux installation IMHO.